# Getting the content of the cell of a selected row from DataGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
string FeeId = grdvw.Rows[index].Cells[0].Text;
```

Is this correct way to retrieve the content of the cell in the selected row? If I use this, I do not get value. So, please suggest the best way.

Comment: Are you using [tag:winforms] or [tag:asp.net]? Modify your question accordingly

Comment: am using the Website

Comment: @Vinay: Please post complete code so that the issue can be reproduced

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a way to do it, you can also do it like:

```
string FeeId = grdvw.Rows[index].Cells[0].Value;
```

Also, if you want to get the values from all the rows you could iterate through the Datagridview like this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grdvw.Rows)
{
   string column0 = row.Cells[0].Value;
   string column1 = row.Cells[1].Value;
   //More code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the value when I try. Here is a sample where I am adding Rows and Columns at runtime:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dCol1 = new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(System.String));
        DataColumn dCol2 = new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(System.String));
        dt.Columns.Add(dCol1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dCol2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
            row1["Col1"] = "One";
            row1["Col2"] = "Two";
            dt.Rows.Add(row1);
        }
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            BoundField bField = new BoundField();
            bField.DataField = col.ColumnName;
            bField.HeaderText = col.ColumnName;
            GridView1.Columns.Add(bField);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        //Bind the datatable with the GridView.
        GridView1.DataBind();
        string str = GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir am using the website .., if i use the ".value" in that it shows an error

Answer (score 0):

```
string FeeId = (grdvw.Rows[index].Cells[0].FindControl("lblfee") as Label).Text;
```

if we use like this we get the answer

Comment: please post something to be useful for others too.